# Is it possible to have a flex box where one box scrolls on overflow and the other doesn't?

Tags: html, css

fairly new to HTML. I have started messing around with flexboxes and have a question. I'm making a website database sort of thing for a TV show I like and am looking to have a side navigation section where the user can find a season or episode and a main content section. The left box is the only one I want to scroll, the right one shouldn't scroll. Is there a way I can just have the left box scroll on overflow and not the right? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<!-- Flex Box One (Left Navigation Section) -->
<div>
    <div class = "flex-container">
    <div style = "flex-basis: 300px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for a season or episode...">
    <div class="sideBox">
    <h1 class="seasonTitle"><h1 style="margin:6px;"> 
    <ul id="myUL">
    </p>
    <li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="#" style="font-size:20px; font-variant: none font-style: none; font-family: sans-serif; text-align: center;"><u>SEASONS:</u><br></a></li>
       <li><a href="IASIPSeason1.html">Season 1<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 2<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 3<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 4<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 5<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 6<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 7<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 8<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 9<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 10<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 11<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 12<br></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Season 13<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 14<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 15<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="IASIPSeason1.html">Season 1<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 2<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 3<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 4<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 5<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 6<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 7<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 8<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 9<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 10<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 11<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 12<br></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Season 13<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 14<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 15<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="IASIPSeason1.html">Season 1<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 2<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 3<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 4<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 5<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 6<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 7<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 8<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 9<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 10<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 11<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 12<br></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Season 13<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 14<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 15<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="IASIPSeason1.html">Season 1<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 2<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 3<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 4<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 5<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 6<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 7<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 8<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 9<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 10<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 11<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 12<br></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Season 13<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 14<br></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Season 15<br></a></li>
    </div>
</div>

<div style = "flex-grow: 2; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">Box 2
</div>

<style>
@media (max-width: 800px) {
.flex-item-right, .flex-item-left {
flex: 100%;
}
}

.flex-container {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
overflow-x: scroll;
height: 1000px;
background-color: #E7E9EB;
}

.flex-container > div {
background-color: #f1f1f1;
margin: 10px;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
font-size: 30px;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: none;
}

.sideBox p {
color: black;
font-size: 17px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-family: none;
text-align: left;
line-height: 35px;
list-style-type: none;
margin: -10px;

}

li {
font-family: default;
}

h1 {
color: black;
text-align: left;
font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
}

#myInput {
width: 250px;
padding: 10px;
height: 35px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-color: black;
background-color: #E7E9EB;
border-style: solid;
margin: 0px;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-left: 1px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
</style>
</div>

<div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible with grid layout. Have a look

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .flex-item-right,
  .flex-item-left {
    flex: 100%;
  }
}

.flex-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 400px auto;
  /*   display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap; */
  /* overflow-x: scroll; */
  /* height: 1000px; */
  background-color: #e7e9eb;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-container .first-child {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: none;
}

.sideBox p {
  color: black;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-family: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 35px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: -10px;
}

li {
  font-family: default;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
}

#myInput {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: #e7e9eb;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Flex Box One (Left Navigation Section) -->
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="first-child" style="flex-basis: 300px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for a season or episode...">
    <div class="sideBox">
      <h1 class="seasonTitle">
        <h1 style="margin:6px;">
          <ul id="myUL">
            </p>
            <li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="#" style="font-size:20px; font-variant: none font-style: none; font-family: sans-serif; text-align: center;"><u>SEASONS:</u><br></a></li>
            <li><a href="IASIPSeason1.html">Season 1<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 2<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 3<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 4<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 5<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 6<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 7<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 8<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 9<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 10<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 11<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 12<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Season 13<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 14<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 15<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="IASIPSeason1.html">Season 1<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 2<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 3<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 4<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 5<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 6<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 7<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 8<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 9<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 10<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 11<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 12<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Season 13<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 14<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 15<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="IASIPSeason1.html">Season 1<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 2<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 3<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 4<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 5<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 6<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 7<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 8<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 9<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 10<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 11<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 12<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Season 13<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 14<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 15<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="IASIPSeason1.html">Season 1<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 2<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 3<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 4<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 5<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 6<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 7<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 8<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 9<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 10<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 11<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 12<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Season 13<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 14<br></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Season 15<br></a></li>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="flex-grow: 2; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">Box 2
  </div>
</div>
```